# Get initial data in custom login form?

Tags: django

I've rolled my own Login form HTML, but I'm having trouble accessing the initial value for the username (so that a failed login attempt returns the form with the email address as before).

My HTML looks like this:

```
<input value="{{ form.initial.username }}" id="id_username" maxlength="254" name="username" type="email" class='form-control'>
```

This doesn't show the incorrectly entered email address (username) after a failed login attempt. If I display the form with `{{ form.as_p }}` then it does. The output HTML is shown below:

```
<input value="incorrect@email.com" id="id_username" maxlength="254" name="username" type="text">
```

What should I be putting into `value=""` instead of `{{ form.initial.username }}`? I've checked and `{{ form.initial }}` is completely empty, is the value available some other way? I'm using the default Django login view to handle the form:

```
url(r'^account/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html', 'SSL': True}, name='login'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form.initial` won't contain failed data, its purpose is only to hold default data for unbound fields.

Try `form.data.username` or `form.username.value` instead.

Comment: `form.data` contained the value I needed.

Comment: `form.data` contains the raw data from the request (usually POST), you can use it but be careful not to consider it "clean"